# Enter not working properly in firefox with contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found this script on here and it seems to help the "bug" with contenteditable and linebreaks a little bit, but there is still something funky going on.

```js
var input = $( '#input' )[0];

$( input ).keypress( function ( e ) {
    var sel, node, offset, text, textBefore, textAfter, range;
   
    // the Selection object
    sel = window.getSelection();
    
    // the node that contains the caret
    node = sel.anchorNode; 

    // if ENTER was pressed while the caret was inside the input field
    if ( node.parentNode === input && e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        
        // prevent the browsers from inserting <div>, <p>, or <br> on their own
        e.preventDefault();

        // the caret position inside the node
        offset = sel.anchorOffset;        

        // insert a '\n' character at that position
        text = node.textContent;
        textBefore = text.slice( 0, offset );
        textAfter = text.slice( offset ) || ' ';
        node.textContent = textBefore + '\n' + textAfter;

        // position the caret after that new-line character
        range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart( node, offset + 1 );
        range.setEnd( node, offset + 1 );
        
        // update the selection
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange( range );
    }
});
```

```css
#input {
    border: 3px solid #07c;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 200px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contentEditable id="input"></div>
```

Just an example to try to recreate what I'm talking about:

Test 1:
In Firefox (I'm on Mac), try writing 'test' in the div and press enter (a space is added at the end, but leave the caret where it is).
Write 'test' again on the new line.
Set the caret at the beginning of the div and write 'test' followed by enter.
Set the caret at the end of the div after the space and press enter.
NO linebreak.

Test 2:
Write `test`, hit cmd+a (ctrl+a on pc) to select all, followed by right arrow key, followed by enter. NO linebreak. It's like the script loses track of the caret if you move it any other way than character by character.

Test 3:
Hit enter 3 times in a row without any other content and you get an error message

Ideas?

Comment: Did you try to add an event listener specifically to the element?

Comment: It all works fine for me (in the snippet; haven't tried on a normal page). Firefox 67, Win10. Even when you say "a space is added at the end", I'm not getting that either by adding a break, only if i manually move the caret.

Comment: Ok, try this. Write `test`, hit cmd+a (ctrl+a on pc) to select all, followed by right arrow key, followed by enter. NO linebreak. It's like the script loses track of the caret if you move it any other way than character by character. It might be Mac related. I don't have a PC to try on.

Comment: Maybe the easiest test. Just hit enter 3 times in a row without any other text and the error comes too.

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks!